# Where are a node data stored in Drupal?

Tags: database, drupal, nodes

I have a working Drupal site that i need to replicate on another server, so that the replicated version doesn't contain custom site information like users data or specific article published on the main site.

So i did a selective dump of the main db, and re-imported in the replicated site. In the specific case of the "node" table, I imported only nodes of the type "page". Now, all went well. The main functions of the site are working, but i have a problem with pages throwing an error "The requested page "/node/page_number" could not be found." with ALL the basic node pages. I can see only views and the front page.

Probably i'm not dumping some information needed by Drupal to display the node. So the question is: where i can find info about basic nodes? I thought porting the table "node" and "node_access" was pretty enough, but really it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `node` table stores only basic information.

I think you did not imported `node_revision` table as well.

Even if you do, dumping tables and re-importing only specific data into another database breaks their connections, by resetting id columns and missing extra data provided by fields and other custom modules.

Consider using Import/Export modules, comparison of which you can find [Comparison of Content and User Import and Export Modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/21338)

Comment: Did it, with no luck. I know about modules, but the export/import process is something i need to do several times during time, so i'm setting up a shell script that does the whole thing, exporting the db dump too. I don't think i can use module via shell, except a few ones, like drush...

Comment: Once I used an interesting solution. I installed [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) on first site which had data. Using this module I did setup Views, which outputs data at http://example1.com/data.csv. And than I've installed [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module on the second site, which had to be synced using data from first site. Feeds module was configured to aggregate data from http://example1.com/data.csv url. So I had second site always synced. This way you don't need to mess with shell scripts. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Really interesting. I'll try. :)

Comment: After some tests, despite i was totally sure i'd included node_revision during dumping, i decided to control the script a bit more deeply. And i node_revision was not imported. Now it's working. You were totally right. Thank you ^^'

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [data_export_import](https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import) module.

What I like about data_export_import is that it is an all-in-one module (for export AND import of data. Whereas as with some other solutions, the import and export stages are done by separate modules, which could mean that extra work is needed ensuring compatibility of the export with the import.)